Point Cloud Library: meaning of segmentation coefficients
I'm doing cylinder segmentation using the Point Cloud Library following the official tutorial:
 // Create the segmentation object for cylinder segmentation and set all the parameters
 seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
 seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_CYLINDER);
 seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
 seg.setNormalDistanceWeight (0.1);
 seg.setMaxIterations (10000);
 seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.05);
 seg.setRadiusLimits (0, 0.1);
 seg.setInputCloud (cloud_filtered2);
 seg.setInputNormals (cloud_normals2);
 
 // Obtain the cylinder inliers and coefficients
 seg.segment (*inliers_cylinder, *coefficients_cylinder);
 std::cerr << "Cylinder coefficients: \n" << *coefficients_cylinder << std::endl;

I get a stream of logs like:
Cylinder coefficients:
header: 
seq: 0 stamp: 0 frame_id: 
values[]
      values[0]:   0.695906
      values[1]:   3.90441
      values[2]:   0.18642
      values[3]:   0.0496929
      values[4]:   0.908354
      values[5]:   -0.415238
      values[6]:   0.258291

How do I interpret the contents of values?

See this overview page for pcl_sample_consensus:

SACMODEL_CYLINDER - used to determine cylinder models. The seven coefficients of the cylinder are given by a point on its axis, the axis direction, and a radius, as: [point_on_axis.x point_on_axis.y point_on_axis.z axis_direction.x axis_direction.y axis_direction.z radius]


Thanks! I did find a Github comment but an "official" source is much better.
